# Windows program level permissions to write to a volume

Tags: windows, permissions, ntfs, amazon-web-services

I'm using a windows machine in AWS which has an FSX volume mounted.  I'd like the volume to be read-only for all processes save for ones from a specific downloading application, which would have read and write access.  I know MacOS has the ability to restrict some permissions at the application level.  If this is possible in Windows, how would one do this?

Comment: What exactly is a FSX volume? You can set the permissions of a volume to anything you want within Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound, FSx for Windows File Server provides fully managed Microsoft Windows file servers, that are backed by a Windows file system.  I'm more trying to figure out if I can set permissions on an application basis instead of a user basis.

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried? I'd guess you're not the first person trying to set up application permissions.